# Template Email Failed to Fetch Email Address, Eventhough the Preview Showed a Proper Email Address

Tags: email, automation, odoo

I'm currently using   Odoo 12.0+e-20181025 . I have been trying to make an email template that will work with an automation where it will send email to the assigned helpdesk team member and also the creator of the ticket. The ticket itself is made via API from a PHP webapp.

The problem I'm having is as the following. I've made the ticket via the PHP webapp. It has been submitted properly without any problem. The automation also worked, as it has assigned a member and then sent two separate emails. The thing is, only the one that is sent to the assigned member but not the creator. It seemingly failed to get the email.​

When I choose the preview, the email is as the following:
Agent  , Customer Service

But when I sent the email, it shows the following:
Agent  , False

My code is as the following:

```
    ${object.user_id.email_formatted | safe} , 
    ${object.x_studio_creator_name_2.email_formatted | safe}
```

Thanks for reading and for the help.

Comment: What model is behind `x_studio_creator_name_2`? Maybe there is an access problem. Which user is used by your webapp to create the ticket and sending the mails?

Comment: The model is helpdesk.ticket and it is linked to the res.partner, the same as the user_id.

Comment: user_id is not a res.partner but res.users instead, that could be a problem, could.

Comment: Hmm, wait, it leads to the same model tho. And I used the administrator account, it should not be a problem? Let me check again. Thanks for the input tho.